# ClassCastException Adventure

Tags: java, classcastexception

I have -

```
class A {
    // contains certain set() and get() methods
}

class B extends A {
    public A getAotherMethod() {
      A a = new A();
      // Contains some logic
      return a
      }
}

class C extends B {
    // contains certain set() and get() methods
}

class D {
    public Object getMethod() {

      B b = new B();
      // Contains some logic
      return b.getAnotherMethod()
     }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    C c = new C();
    D d = new D();
    c = (C) d.getMethod(); // This is giving me ClassCastException
}
```

Comment: "I have a car. When I drive against a wall, it breaks."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
d.getMethod();
```

This will call **b.getAnotherMethod()** internally, which has

```
A a = new A();
// Contains some logic
return a
```

The object of **class A** cannot cast to **class C**

We can assign **subclass object** to  **superclass reference** but we cannot assign **superclass object** to **subclass reference** what is done by you in this case.